# Controlling significant digits in knitr figure captions

Tags: latex, knitr

I'm having trouble finding a way to globally control the number of digits output when constructing a fig.cap. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<first_chunk, echo = FALSE>>=
options(digits = 3)
@

<<second_chunk, fig.cap = paste("Pi equals",  pi), echo = FALSE>>=
plot(pi)
@

This is pi: \Sexpr{pi}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I can manually set it for each chunk using round():

```
<<second_chunk, fig.cap = paste("Pi equals",  round(pi, 3)), echo = FALSE>>=
```

but is there a way to set it globally for all chunks?

Comment: `knitr` usually respects `options("digits")`. The behavior you observe is due to the fact that automatic rounding only applies when a numeric variable is printed. By using `paste` a character string is created (from concatenating a string and a float that's converted to string in your case) and after that `knitr` cannot do anything about the rounding anymore. I think this behavior is correct. You need to distinguish between "print numerics" and "process numeric, converting them to string". There's no rounding in the latter case.

Comment: I see, thanks. And I suppose there is no way to modify the `as.character()` output via a global option?

Comment: There's always a way. ;) See the answer below for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To reforumlate the question a little bit (because the observed behavior is not related to chunk options vs. `\Sexpr`), let's say:

> Why does `print(pi)` respect `options(digits = 3)` but `print(paste("The value of pi is", pi))` does not? And what can I do about it?

The reason is that `getOption("digits")` applies only when printing numberic values (cf. `?options`). Therefore, there will be no rounding when a numeric value is coerced to `character` and then printed as in the second case with `print(paste(…`.

Having answered *why* this happens, let's turn to the "What can I do about it?" part.

One very simple solution is to use `sprintf`. Actually, this is a good idea in many cases as the code is very easy to read. Here, we can additionally benefit from the formatting options by using `%f`:

```
> print(sprintf("The value of pi is %.4f", pi))
[1] "The value of pi is 3.1416"
```

An alternative is to stick to the `print(paste(…` structure but eliminate the need of manual rounding. One advantage could be that `getOption("digits")` is used (as opposed to the `sprintf` approach).

To this end, define `paste2` as follows:

```
paste2 <- function(..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL, digits = getOption("digits")) {

  arguments <- list(...)

  for (i in seq_along(arguments)) {
    if (is.numeric(arguments[[i]])) {
      arguments[[i]] <- round(arguments[[i]], digits = digits)
    }
  }

  if (!missing(sep)) {
    arguments$sep <- sep
  }

  if (!missing(collapse)) {
    arguments$collapse <- collapse
  }

  return(do.call(what = paste, args = arguments))
}
```

*Use `paste2` with care!* I tried to avoid as many unwanted differences to `paste` as possible, but there still might be "unexpected features".

`paste2` can be used to combine numerics and character variables, rounding the former to `getOption("digits")` number of digits by default:

```
> options(digits = 3)
> print(paste2("The value of pi is", pi))
[1] "The value of pi is 3.142"

> options(digits = 1)
> print(paste2("The value of pi is", pi))
[1] "The value of pi is 3.1"
```